# How to change React-Bootstrap NavDropdown menu background color?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap` in my application and I needed to change the background color of the menu of `NavDropdown` component. I used modular `css` for my react application. I've tried background-color but no effect.

[React-Bootstrap NavDropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Z7H.png)

`Index.js`:

```
<NavDropdown
    title={style.dropdownTitle}
    id={style.dropdownMenu}
    align="end"
>
    <NavDropdown.Item
        href="#action/3.1"
        className={style.dropdownItem}
    >
        Profile
    </NavDropdown.Item>
    <NavDropdown.Item
        href="#action/3.1"
        className={style.dropdownItem}
    >
        Learnings
    </NavDropdown.Item>
    <NavDropdown.Item
        href="#action/3.1"
        className={style.dropdownItem}
    >
        Logout
    </NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
```

`index.module.css`:

```
#dropdownMenu {
  background-color: #002037;
  color: #e2dec0 !important;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

.dropdownItem {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #e2dec0 !important;
}
```

I tried modifying it in browser's developer tools 
Before: [Chrome Browser Developer Tools (BEFORE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCThG.png) 
After: [Chrome Browser Developer Tools (AFTER)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc0Gk.png)

[Chrome Browser Developer Tools (Full)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykEXm.png)

Comment: Have you inspected the element in your browser to see what styles are being applied? Does your selector match? Is it being overridden by something? It's pretty hard for us to help with this, but it's pretty easy for you to see what's happening.

Comment: Are the rest of the styles getting applied?

Comment: @Woohaik Yes, the rest of the styles are getting applied except for background-color.

Comment: Yeah you need to inspect the element and check that is the background color _actually_ coming from that. I suspect there is some other element that actually provides the background

Comment: I updated the question above. I added images using my browser's developer tools.

Comment: @EtotheI That means another style has preference or a better scope applying the styles, check in the inspector in the browser, right click in the dropdown, inspect and will show all classes and IDs that are applying styles to your element, there must be another one with the light background, you could get more specific in the CSS rule or using the !important. If this doesnt work try overriding the other rule that have the light color.

Comment: Seeing your browser's developer tools, the ID selector is not working, check if the element has the desired ID in your browser.

Comment: I added full image of my developer tools, I can't seem to find where to include it from react-bootstrap's implementation of NavDropdown. I added `!important` to background-color, but still no effect.

Comment: The ID Is not being applied, try using a class instead

Answer (score 1):

I added a temporary fix for now. I selected the next div element from dropdownMenu class that indicates the dropdown-menu found in developer tools:

```
#dropdownMenu + div {
  background-color: #002037 !important;
}

.dropdownItem:hover {
  color: #002037 !important;
}
```

[NavDropdown Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTr7y.png)